# edittext auto adjust height

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a edittext, it's one-line height now. Then I keep entering letters until it changes a new line. How to increase the edittext height according to the new line changes?

Answer (score 0):

edittext.getLayoutParams().height=28;

look up display metrics for using dp instead of px

also check if edittext has a setMinLines() method you can use.  I have not checked.